# Can't add double values to list dynamically, System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, dynamic-arrays

I always getting this following error:

'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

I am receiving double inputs dynamically from a PLC. I am not able to save the inputs inside a list. I dont know why. can anyone help?

```
string str = stringArray[1];
double value = double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
List<double> list = new List<double>();
List<double> result = new List<double>();
while (true)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 3 - 1; ++i)
    {
        list.Add(value);
        result[i] = (list[i - 1] + list[i] + list[i + 1]) / 3; //The error is here
        dataHub.ServerTemp(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: You are not adding anything to str are you?

Comment: Yes, i did comment where i get the error

Comment: There are so many coding errors here. I think you should start looking in to some tutorials on C#

Comment: Yes i am. I can print the "value" in a textbox

Comment: what else do you expect when the list has one entry (list[0]) and you are trying to get the list[0] and list[1] and list[2] at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 1; i < 3 - 1; ++i)
```

is essentially the same as `i = 1` (start with 1, but don't go as far as 2)

So what your code is trying to do is:

1. Add a double (`value`) to list `list`
2. Update the second item in list `result` (**first problem, `result` is initially empty**) with the average of first, second and third item in `list` (**second problem - `list` has one element**).

Answer (score 0):

result[i] does not yet exist.  That is why you are getting the out of range error.